Validation Issue on Interactive Grid column
My validation on interactive grid showing proper error message but even after throwing validation its saving that value in database. I'm not understanding why its happening.
Anyone know what is the reason behind that?
enter image description here
when I select this number from select list it throws error which is right but problem is it is saving it in DB.
Is there any why i can implement this validation using Dynamic action and use alert box for showing custom validation?
Thanks In advance. waiting for response
I tried to use Function Body Returning Boolean, Function body returning Error text and Rows Returned type of validation but it did not solve the issue of saving the value in DB.
EDIT -
This is My Insert Query in debug mode
This is My Validation
I have shared 2 Snapshots of Debug. one is of insert statement and one is validation. I did not understand what is problem there

Well... you have not shared any code so it is impossible to tell you what is going wrong. However... that message indicates NOT that the validation is failing, it indicates that the apex engine is failing to execute the validation.
Run the page in debug mode and check debug - that will show you exactly which statement is erroring out or... share the validation code. In the end it makes more sense for you to get familiar with debugging an apex application.
You state I tried to use Function Body Returning Boolean, Function body returning Error text and Rows Returned type . That shouldn't make a difference - something is wrong in your code. Several members are actively following this tag and will be able to help if code is shared.

DECLARE
V_ATTRIBUTE NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT 1
INTO V_ATTRIBUTE
FROM ADMIN.XX_SALES_ORDER_TBL
WHERE ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER10 = :ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER10
AND ((GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_CHAR21 LIKE '%B%')
OR (GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_CHAR21 LIKE '%-%')
OR (GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_CHAR21 IS NULL))
AND GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER14 = 'US21';
IF V_ATTRIBUTE = 1 THEN
RETURN TRUE;
ELSE RETURN FALSE;
END IF;
END;

Basically, ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER10 is my Primary key, GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_CHAR21 either contains "B" or "-" in it and GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER14 should equal to 'US21'

ok... please do not post additional information in a comment. Instead, edit your question and add the additional information. Comments don't allow proper code formatting. But... I suggested to run the page in debug and check that. What did that return ? My guess is that it raised a no data found since you're not trapping that in your code. A SELECT INTO without an aggregate function will raise a no data found exception

From debug it seems the validation is firing fine. However, I now notice that you mention "Dynamic Action" ? A dynamic action should not be used for a validation. I'm unable to see why this is not working.  If you're able to create a reproducible case on apex.oracle.com (using emp/dept sample dataset) and share the credentials here I'm happy to take a look.

I found out the issue was that the Update Process was in the "After Submit" section and not "Processing" That's why it was causing the issue. Thanks Koen Lostrie for your Help.
